# Node / Express generate calendar URL

Tags: node.js, express

I have a database with a bunch of dates and an online overview where you can view them, now I know I can copy a URL from my Google Agenda and import this in other calendar clients so I can view the events there.

I want to generate an Express endpoint where I fetch every event **every time the endpoint is called** and return it in a format that can be imported by other calendar clients. Now with packages like [iCal-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ical-generator) I could generate, read, and return the file whenever a user requests the URL. but it feels redudent to write a file to my storage to then read it, return it and delete it every time it's requested.

What is the most effiecent way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating the file/calendar data on every request, you could implement a simple caching mechanism. That is, upon start of your node app you generate the calendar data and put it in your cache with corresponding time to live value. Once the data has expired or new entries are inserted into your DB you invalidate the cache, re-generate the data and cache it again.

Here's a very simple example for an in-memory cache that uses the [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) library:

```
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');
const cacheService = new NodeCache();
// ...
const calendarDataCacheKey = 'calender-data';
// at the start of your app, generate the calendar data and cache it with a ttl of 30 min
cacheCalendarData(generateCalendarData());

function cacheCalendarData (calendarData) {
  cacheService.set(calendarDataCacheKey, calendarData, 1800);
}

// in your express handler first try to get the value from the cache
// if not - generate it and cache it
app.get('/calendar-data', (req, res) => {
  let calendarData = cacheService.get(calendarDataCacheKey);
  if (calendarData === undefined) {
    calendarData = generateCalendarData();
    cacheCalendarData(calendarData);
  }
  res.send(calendarData);
});
```

If your app is scaled horizontally you should consider using [redis](https://redis.io/).

Answer (score 1):

100% untested, but I have code similar to this that exports to a .csv from a db query, and it might get you close:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

async function getCalendar(req, res) {
  const events = await db.getCalendarEvents();
  const filename = 'some_file.ics';

  res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'text/calendar',
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${filename}`,
  });

  const input = new Readable({ objectMode: true });
  input.pipe(res)
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('SOME ERROR', err);
      res.status(500).end();
    });

  events.forEach(e => input.push(e));
  input.push(null);
}
```

if you were going to use the iCal generator package, you would do your transforms within the `forEach` method before pushing to the stream.